# Join tables based on many columns

Tags: join, sas, macros, proc

I would like to left join table A and table B by one column in table A and 30 columns in table B.
[table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXOhg.png)
[table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL8MD.png)

I used to use R language but I have to do this in SAS for some reasons.

For the starter I tried this

```
proc sql;
    create table ipdte_gbd as
    select A.*, B.*
    from IPDTE.ipdte103pt3 as A
    left join GBD.GBD_expand_test1 as B
    on A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = B.cause_code_uni_1
    or A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = B.cause_code_uni_2
    or A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = B.cause_code_uni_3
    or A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = B.cause_code_uni_4
    or A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = B.cause_code_uni_5;
quit;
```

and I got

```
ERROR: Expression using = has components that are of different data types.
```

This method looked silly, and then I tried macro(I'm extremely not familiar with macro)
things went worse and worse.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying you are trying to compare a number from one dataset with a character string from the other.

Best option is to fix the source datasets to use the same type of values for the corresponding variables.

If you do need to compare a number to a string in general it will work better to convert the string to a number because there is only one way to represent a number as a number, but the same number can be represented many different way as a string.

Let's assume it is the first pair that are mismatched and the variable from the A side is the numeric one then you could perhaps use something like:

```
on A.ICD9CM_1_v3 = input(B.cause_code_uni_1,32.)
```

But if your variables are really supposed to be ICD9 codes then they should be strings and not numbers.  Many ICD9 codes might LOOK like numbers, but they are not.  The location of the decimal place and number of leading and trailing digits included all have meaning in ICD9 codes.  The values in your photograph do not look like ICD9 codes, but it is common to save a byte by not storing the decimal point, so perhaps they are valid values.

To really join those two tables efficiently you should first transpose the second one (the one with many variables that all contain ICD9 codes) so that it also has one variable with the ICD9 codes and then join on that.  The type of the variables will still need to match.